# Error Code while writing a Snake Game with Java

Tags: java

I recently started to teach myself some Python and Java. So I tried to write some easy programs but with this snake game I tried I discovered a mysterious problem. Maybe someone of you knows where the error is.

the code:

```java
for(var i = 0; < snake.tail.length;i++){
...
```

If you need something else to engage this problem please let me know

Julian

Answer (score 1):

you're missing an "i", and java doesn't use var, use `int` instead:

```
for(int i = 0; i < snake.tail.length; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have the wrong condition construction:

```java
   < snake.tail.length
^
|
|
```

You don't have anything on the left site. Probably you need the `i` variable here.

```java
i < snake.tail.length
```